# powershell script to remove multiple folders

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like a script to remove multiple folders from beneath each users douments and settings.

Example folders:

Desktop
Favorites
mmerge
my documents
nethood
printhood
recent
sentto
start menu
windows
application data
local settings

I would like it to delete everything except the following.

my documents
mmerge
desktop
favorites

Is there a way to scropt this or remove all with an exception list perhaps?
This is the same for all users.

> path e:\redirected\%username%\

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to employ the [Remove-Item](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176938.aspx) cmdlet but before doing so, you seriously need to review your requirements.  For example, removing all folders under local setting or application data is likely to break stuff (i.e. installed applications).  You'll also need to test for file locks and define a strategy for dealing with files and folders that can't be deleted whilst the user is logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
ls '\Documents and Settings' | ? { ! ($_.psiscontainer -and $_ -match "my documents|mmerge|desktop|favorites") } | rm -rec -force -whatif
```

Obviously you need to be very careful with the `rm -rec` and remove the **-whatif**. ;) Add **-force** to the `ls` (Get-ChildItem) if you want to make hidden folders visible to your destruction.